# xamarin replace new view in renderer

Tags: android, xamarin

Hello I am trying to make a renderer for boxview in Android. I need to add in render new view. The view cannot be displayed. Can somebody tell me what's wrong and explain me ho does it work?

This is method in my renderer.

```
     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var activity = this.Context as Activity;

        if (e.OldElement == null) {
            // Connect the control to its renderer.
            PKInputView inputView = (PKInputView)this.Element;

            var viewGroup = (global::Android.Views.ViewGroup)ViewGroup;

            //Creating Layout
            global::Android.Widget.RelativeLayout layout = new global::Android.Widget.RelativeLayout(viewGroup.Context);
            //Creating TextView
            global::Android.Widget.TextView text = new global::Android.Widget.TextView(this.Context);
            text.Text = "ahoj";
            text.SetHeight(30);
            text.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Red);

            //Set up layers
            layout.AddView(text);
            viewGroup.AddView(layout);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace control, You should derive renderer from viewrenderer. 
Try These Code. And this vdo

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PKInputView), typeof(PKInputViewRenderer))]

public class PKInputViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<PKInputView,global::Android.Widget.TextView>, CCDataSource
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<PKInputView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        // Connect the control to its renderer.
        PKInputView inputView = e.NewElement ?? e.OldElement;;

        // Creating TextView
        global::Android.Widget.TextView text = new global::Android.Widget.TextView(this.Context);
        text.Text = "ahoj";
        text.SetHeight(30);
        text.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Red);

        SetNativeControl(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace e.OldElement with this.Control:

```
if (this.Control == null) {
```

remove this as it would throw an exception (unless BoxView inherits from PKInputView):

```
    PKInputView inputView = (PKInputView)this.Element;
```

then at the end of the scope of the if statement set the native view:

```
    this.SetNativeControl(viewGroup);
}
```

I assume the renderer looks something like this:

```
public class BoxViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<BoxView, global::Android.Views.ViewGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to include whole class, because your advices didn't work.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PKInputView), typeof(PKInputViewRenderer))]

namespace takeapayment.Droid.Renderers {

public class PKInputViewRenderer : BoxRenderer, CCDataSource {
    /*
    //header
    private global::Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout header = Android.Widget.AbsoluteLayout();
    private TextView title = new TextView();
    private global::Android.Widget.Button saveButton = new Button();
    */

    protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var activity = this.Context as Activity;

        if (e.OldElement == null) {
            // Connect the control to its renderer.
            PKInputView inputView = (PKInputView)this.Element;

            var viewGroup = (global::Android.Views.ViewGroup)ViewGroup;

            //Creating Layout
            global::Android.Widget.RelativeLayout layout = new global::Android.Widget.RelativeLayout(viewGroup.Context);
            //Creating TextView
            global::Android.Widget.TextView text = new global::Android.Widget.TextView(this.Context);
            text.Text = "ahoj";
            text.SetHeight(30);
            text.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Red);

            //Set up layers
            layout.AddView(text);
            viewGroup.AddView(layout);
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

this vdo will show all aspect of custom renderer.
https://developer.xamarin.com/videos/cross-platform/xamarinforms-custom-renderers/